# Create a Word Tag in MS Access

Tags: string, vba, ms-access, trend

I'm trying to generate a Word Tag in Ms access using VBA or Query to view common trends in a string (MEMO Field).

Using VBA is it possible to search through a string to look for repeated words?

Kindest regards

Max

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use *Split*:

```
Dim Words As Variant
Words = Split(Sentence)
```

Then loop array *Words* to find dupes:

```
Dim Word As Integer
For Word = LBound(Words) To UBound(Words)
    ' run search code for each word.
Next
```